# Why pressable is not taking value(as a type) for custom styling? in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to add the custom type of style type which i specified in the styling, given below:

```
container_PRIMARY: {
    backgroundColor: 'pink',

},
container_TERTIARY: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',

},
```

but the error is it is not accepting it. don't know either it is syntax error or something else. Kindly let me know what is the error with the code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you wanted to substitute value of `type` variable in key for `customButtonStyles`, for which you wanted to use a template string.

Template literals are delimited with backtick(`) characters and not with single quote (').

```js
customButtonStyles[`container_${type}`]
```